# Can't return std::unique_ptr<> with derived type

Tags: c++, inheritance, unique-ptr

I have the following templated function:

```
template<typename T = CRecordset>
std::unique_ptr<T> ExecuteSqlQuery(LPCTSTR pszSqlQuery = nullptr, RecordsetMode nMode = RecordsetMode::read)
{
    ASSERT(m_Database.IsOpen());
    std::unique_ptr<ITableRecordset> prs = std::make_unique<T>(&m_Database);
    if (!ExecuteSqlQuery(prs.get(), pszSqlQuery, nMode))
        prs.reset();
    return prs;
}
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
auto prs = db.ExecuteSqlQuery<CCustomerRecordset>(nullptr, RecordsetMode::bulkRead);
```

`CCustomerRecordset` derives from `CTableRecordset<>`, and `CTableRecordset<>` derives from `ITableRecordset`.

However, the return statement in the function gives me an error:

```
Error C2440 'return': cannot convert from std::unique_ptr<ITableRecordset,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'std::unique_ptr<CCustomerRecordset,std::default_delete<_Ty>>'  
    with  
    [  
        _Ty=ITableRecordset  
    ]  
    and  
    [  
        _Ty=CCustomerRecordset  
    ]
```

Since `CCustomerRecordset` is a type of `ITableRecordset`, why can't I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example reduces to this:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};

A *a = new B;
B *b = a;
```

The return statement is trying to return a `unique_ptr<ITableRecordset>` where a `unique_ptr<CCustomerRecordset>` is expected. It's a downcast, and won't happen implicitly. A way to fix it would be to make full use of the concrete type throughout the function template. So instead of converting to the interface:

```
auto prs = std::make_unique<T>(&m_Database);
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. The function is called from a method that needs a base pointer because it doesn't know the type, so I guess I was caught up thinking about that. So what if I have a similar issue passing a pointer to a method? Should I just cast it?

Comment: @JonathanWood - If you are certain of the types involved then yes, cast it. Something like `static_cast<B*>(a)` will do. If you want an added bit of safety and checking of polymorphic types, then a `dynamic_cast` should be used instead.